# Как лучше?

Tags: грамотная-речь

"Чашка кофе" или "чашка с кофе"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Смотря что вы имеете в виду. Недостаточно контекста, чтобы сказать, какой вариант лучше.
В варианте "чашка кофе" смысловой акцент на кофе (в данном случае я не делаю грамматический разбор словосочетания). Например: "*Я бы выпил чашку кофе*" (понятно, что выпить хочется кофе, а не тару). В этой фразе "чашка" - обозначение количества кофе. В варианте "чашка с кофе" главным фигурантом является именно чашка как предмет посуды. А какая уж там чашка - с кофе, с  чаем или с молоком - это уже атрибутика. Например: "*Убери со стола чашку с кофе, а вазу с фруктами можешь оставить*".